# tinymce textarea value is empty after POST in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, tinymce

I'm very annoyed on this one. I use the latest version of TinyMCE with Jquery (tried also just TinyMCE) and when I submit the form with the textarea in it it causes problems in IE - the value is blank. I tried everything and the result is the same ... in IE9. Every other browser is ok.

Comment: please provide your tinymce configuration and if possible a test page

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use ckeditor http://ckeditor.com/ , I am having the same issue when one of my team mates suggested to use this. The best thing about ckeditor is that its been used by .Net community, and if they are using it that means there won't be any conflicts with IE's. :)

Cheers.. :)